# How can you use magnets to rotate a shaft, which in turn powers a generator?

Tags: electromagnetism, power

I recently was given the task to create power using magnets, I would think that if I were to put some same poled magnets together, and they were facing the same poled magnets, they would repel and rotate around a shaft.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot 'create' power using magnets, you can only convert power from one form to another. As per the principle of conservation of energy, this can't be done. Your set up of same poled magnets facing same poled magnets would rotate momentarily due to the repulsion, but soon come to rest at an *equilibrium* position - a position where the the repulsion from one magnet cancels off the repulsion due to another. What really can be done by using such set ups of magnets is to convert mechanical energy into electrical energy, or vice versa. To achieve this, you would need to understand [Faraday's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_induction), and the [force law for current carrying conductors](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/forwir2.html) which underly the working principles of devices such as generators and motors. Here are some other links which may get you started - http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/motorac.html#c2 , http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/motdc.html#c2 .

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a generator then [this](http://www.wikihow.com/Make-a-Simple-Electric-Generator) might help.
And if you really want to use the energy which is produced while the magnets repel you can use a [piezoelectric generator](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jiu9zL10lIc).